# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') at it.fromString

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to order my 'orders' collection in descending order and i am getting this error and i cant seem to figure out why.

```
 const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const userOrders = onSnapshot(
        doc(db, "users", user?.id, "orders").orderBy("created", "desc"));
           setOrders(
           userOrders.map((doc) => ({
           id: doc.id,
           data: doc.data(),
         }))
      );
    } else {
      setOrders([]);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

I am new to v9 modular firebase and if someone could help me out with this i'd appreciate it.

--UPDATE--

So i used a hardcoded value for my `user?.id` and also restructured my code to:

```
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      if (user) {
        const collRef = doc(
          db,
          "users",
          "ZnvtmiBtrafmqHY9AegcwYU2cKV2",
          "orders"
        );
        const docSnap = await onSnapshot(collRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
        setOrders(docSnap);
        orders.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }));
      } else {
        setOrders([]);
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, [user]);
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Orders.jsx:41 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/ZnvtmiBtrafmqHY9AegcwYU2cKV2/orders has 3.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: You mention an "error" ; it would be wise to paste the error trace in your question

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code:

1. By doing `doc(db, "users", user?.id, "orders").orderBy("created", "desc");` you try to call the [`orderBy()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#orderby) method on a `DocumentReference`, which is not possible (and actually this `DocumentReference` is wrongly defined). You need to call the `orderBy()` method on a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference).
2. You cannot directly call [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) on `userOrders`, since `onSnapshot()`  attaches a listener for DocumentSnapshot events and returns a function that can be called to cancel the snapshot listener.

I would suggest you read the following documentation:

- [Get data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). In your case you should probably use the `get()` method to to get the data once.
- [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). See the first example and how a `Query` is defined with `const q = query(citiesRef, orderBy("name"), limit(3));`.

---

In your case, the query should be declared as follows:

```
const collRef = collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders");
const q = query(collRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
 console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
// Or querySnapshot.docs().map(...);
```

Comment: Hey @VictorChoe, did you have time to look a the proposed answer?

Comment: Hi @Renaund Tarnec, I used your example above and I was still getting the same error. I even simulated the query in my firestore cloud database and ```.collection("orders")
.orderBy("created", "desc")``` is correct. It is saying the error is occuring at ```const collRef = collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders");
``` but that looks correct to me as well.

Comment: Are you sure `user?.id` has the correct value? Can you try with an hard coded value?

Comment: @Renuad Tarnec I updated the original question with a hardcoded value for ```user?.id``` and a restructured function.